# WebGL - cannot reader property createShader of null

Tags: javascript, null, webgl

I am following a book called professional WebGL, I am hand writing stuff making sure of my understanding, I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>2-1 A first WebGL example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

        void main() {
            gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        }
    </script>

    <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;

        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gl;
        var canvas;
        var shaderProgram;
        var vertexBuffer;

        /*Function to create the webgl context*/
        function createGLContext(canvas) {
            var names = ["webgl", "experimental-webgl"];
            var context = null;
            for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                try {
                    context = canvas.getContext(names[i]);
                } catch(e) {
                    if(context) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(context) {
                context.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
                context.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
            } else {
                alert("Failed to create webgl context");
            }

            return context;
        }

        function loadShaderFromDOM(id) {
            var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);

            //if we don't find an element with the specified id
            //we do an early exit
            if(!shaderScript) {
                return null;
            }

            //loop through the children for the found DOM element and
            //build up the shader source code as a string.
            var shaderSource = "";
            var currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;
            while(currentChild) {
                if(currentChild.nodeType == 3) {
                    //3 corresponds to TEXT_NODE
                    shaderSource += currentChild.textContent;
                }
                currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
            }

            var shader;
            if(shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
                shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            } else if(shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
                shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            } else {
                return null;
            }

            gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
            gl.compileShader(shader);

            if(!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
                alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
                return null;
            }
            return shader;
        }

        /*Function to setup the shaders*/
        function setupShaders() {
            var vertexShader = loadShaderFromDOM("shader-vs");
            var fragmentShader = loadShaderFromDOM("shader-fs");

            shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
            gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

            if(!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
                alert("Failed toe setup shaders");
            }

            gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

            shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
        }

        /*Function to setup the buffers*/
        function setupBuffers() {
            vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
            var triangleVertices = [
                0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
                -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                0.5, -0.5, 0.0
            ];
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(triangleVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            vertexBuffer.itemSize = 3;
            vertexBuffer.numberOfItems = 3;
        }

        /*Function to draw the triangle*/
        function draw() {
            gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
            gl.celar(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, vertexBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertexBuffer.numberOfItems);
        }

        /*Function to kick everything off*/
        function startup() {
            canvas = document.getElementById("myGLCanvas");
            gl = createGLContext(canvas);
            setupShaders();
            setupBuffers();
            gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1);
            draw();
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="startup()">
<canvas id="myGLCnvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

for some reason, it says that it can't read property null for `createShader` here:
`shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);`

But it doesn't complain at all for the same declaration but with the fragment shader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly changed version.
`gl.celar` was wrong and main loop for getting context.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>2-1 A first WebGL example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script id="shader-vs" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec3 aVertexPosition;

        void main() {
            gl_Position = vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
        }
    </script>

    <script id="shader-fs" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;

        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var gl;
        var canvas;
        var shaderProgram;
        var vertexBuffer;

        /*Function to create the webgl context*/
        function createGLContext(canvas) {
            var names = ["webgl", "experimental-webgl"];
            gl = null;
            for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {

                gl = canvas.getContext(names[i]);
                if(gl)
                    break;
            }
            if(gl) {
                gl.viewportWidth = canvas.width;
                gl.viewportHeight = canvas.height;
            } else {
                console.log("Failed to create webgl context");
            }
        }

        function loadShaderFromDOM(id) {
            var shaderScript = document.getElementById(id);

            //if we don't find an element with the specified id
            //we do an early exit
            if(!shaderScript) {
                return null;
            }

            //loop through the children for the found DOM element and
            //build up the shader source code as a string.
            var shaderSource = "";
            var currentChild = shaderScript.firstChild;
            while(currentChild) {
                if(currentChild.nodeType == 3) {
                    //3 corresponds to TEXT_NODE
                    shaderSource += currentChild.textContent;
                }
                currentChild = currentChild.nextSibling;
            }

            var shader;
            if(shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-fragment") {
                shader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            } else if(shaderScript.type == "x-shader/x-vertex") {
                shader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            } else {
                return null;
            }

            gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
            gl.compileShader(shader);

            if(!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
                alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
                return null;
            }
            return shader;
        }

        /*Function to setup the shaders*/
        function setupShaders() {
            var vertexShader = loadShaderFromDOM("shader-vs");
            var fragmentShader = loadShaderFromDOM("shader-fs");

            shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
            gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
            gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

            if(!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
                alert("Failed toe setup shaders");
            }

            gl.useProgram(shaderProgram);

            shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "aVertexPosition");
        }

        /*Function to setup the buffers*/
        function setupBuffers() {
            vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
            var triangleVertices = [
                0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
                -0.5, -0.5, 0.0,
                0.5, -0.5, 0.0
            ];
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(triangleVertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            vertexBuffer.itemSize = 3;
            vertexBuffer.numberOfItems = 3;
        }

        /*Function to draw the triangle*/
        function draw() {
            gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.viewportWidth, gl.viewportHeight);
            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            gl.vertexAttribPointer(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute, vertexBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(shaderProgram.vertexPositionAttribute);

            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertexBuffer.numberOfItems);
        }

        /*Function to kick everything off*/
        function startup() {
            canvas = document.getElementById("myGLCnvas");
            createGLContext(canvas);
            setupShaders();
            setupBuffers();
            gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1);
            draw();
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="startup()">
<canvas id="myGLCnvas" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, I also noticed: canvas = document.getElementById("myGLCnvas"); and in the div it was spelled differently: myGLCanvas.

Comment: I found that keeping the main loop for getting the context same still worked after changing the div misspell...strange?

Comment: Not strange at all. You passed the variable `gl = createGLContext()`. But anyway you do it, you need to set `gl` var because that's the one you use. Please accept my answer and perhaps upvote it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, where I have one page that is an open scene that starts as a html that works and the other page is a death match with and the map and unitsize using and external main file and not hard coded and it doesn't work. Both pages are the same code

The difference was between `three.js` and `three.min.js`. The .min file worked.